# Addressable RGB LED 'curtain' - how are parallel strings addressed?

Tags: led, rgb, interconnect

I bought a [cheap LED curtain device](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004662802792.html).. its 20x20 fully addressable LEDs. Its pretty nifty, and now I want to make one myself. *(in fact, I want to eventually make 20 x 20 x 20 ... but let’s learn to walk before we learn to run eh?)*

By 'curtain' I mean like hanging beads- separate strands, not like a sheet of fabric. Like you find in doorways sometimes.

So this is what I do know (or believe to be correct):

- Addressable LED data is are generally passed along in one long serial line
- There is usually three wires - pwd, gnd and data
- Each LED has data in, and data out, and passes the data on in serial
- I've tinkered about with a single strip, and a matrix display on Arduino before.

Now with these 'curtains' we have many strips hanging down, and each strip is joined at the top 'serially'.  [image: its curtains for you]

**So I really don't understand how this is achievable with normal addressable LEDs, with only three wires. Is it possible just to connect all the data lines as depicted, and somehow address in software?**
When connected as described, I had expected all strips would each illuminate identically.  i.e. all the top LEDs would be the same, all the 2nd LEDs down would be the same, etc
How could we differentiate each strip?

The top looks like this:

[image: the top bit].

You can clearly see its three core wire. I've opend this, and there is no electronics in it.

I've seen [projects](https://learn.adafruit.com/1500-neopixel-led-curtain-with-raspberry-pi-fadecandy/overview) where each string has data provided separately, but that is not what is of interest to me.

I'm also aware of [4-wire products](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005633830417.html) which literally have a data return, and it makes perfect sense to me how these could be used - but the **mystery is the three wire setup.**

Thanks!

Comment: For all we know, the T piece could have a chip that starts forwarding data after data for first string is received so then the next string can get data.

Comment: Nope, with straight connections it's not really possible. You could, though, feed a 4th cable from the end of the first strand end to the start of 2nd strand and so forth. Perhaps, Justme's assumtion is correct.

Comment: As I mentioned, I opened a T piece, and there's nothing in it.
But then I realised I opened the last one, where there would be no need for anything chip - D'OH!  Will dismantle the penultimate t-piece tomorrow.

Comment: Nope.  absolutely zero electronics in the T piece  - it literally branches off the three wires for the strand. So there _is_ something clever going on.

Comment: Something clever:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ge8Swdd9Srw

https://github.com/Aircoookie/WLED/issues/1312